# Textbox to Get Specified Value from dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I want to get a specific row value from a specific dataset using the `First` function in SSRS.
The dataset returns values like:

```
From  To   Value
1     30   10
30    60   20
60    100  30
```

Also:

- I have a parameter that has an integer value from 1 to 100.
- I want to get the dataset value if the parameter is between `From` and `To` and
- I want to put this value in Textbox **not in a Tablix**.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Expr in your textbox:

```
=First(Fields!FieldName.Value, "YourDataset")
```

Example:

```
=First(Fields!Name.Value, "GetName")
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

Use the parameter as two filters **on** the dataset, `>= From` and `< To`.

Then an expression in your text box like `=First(Value.Value, "dataset")`.

Answer (score -1):

You should first create a list (in order to relate to it a `DataSet`).

Then, inside the list, put a textbox and define the following expression:

`=First(Field!Value.Value)`

This will do the job :)

Answer (score -1):

SSRS is a reporting tool not an application. You can either write your queries or SP to receive the value before generating the report, or otherwise i would recommend an application with a exporting functionality (you can even manipulate this to use SSRS to export your final report). Third party tools like Telerik can also maybe help.